# ionic 2 base64 quicktime video not playing

Tags: html, image, video, base64, ionic2

I have a base64 jpeg and a base64 quicktime video. I can show the jpg but the video won't play.

My HTML is as follows:

```html
<div *ngIf="step.type == 'PHOTO'" (click)="editStep(step.id, step.rev, i)" class="pu-plan-details-step-photo">
  <img [src]="step.attachment">
</div>

<div *ngIf="step.type == 'VIDEO'" (click)="editStep(step.id, step.rev, i)" class="pu-plan-details-step-video">
  <video controls="controls" width="100%">
    <source type="video/quicktime" [src]="step.attachment">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

I get the video play button but clicking on it does not play the video.

Both the jpg and the video are pulled down from a server as base64 files. I have confirmed that the video plays ok on the server.

For the jpg I prefix the base64 string with `data:image/jpeg;base64,` for the quicktime (mov) video I prefix the base64 string with `data:video/quicktime;base64,`

Comment: Can you share a link to the video - it sounds like it may be a video format issue?

Comment: I managed to get the base64 item to play in the end so my need to validate it has gone away. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @BillNoble how u base64 video/quicktime in video element?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved the issue by now but if you didn't I figured out when I was having the same problem you're browser probably doesn't support .mov files. Because when I was trying to upload those files to my page it was doing the exact same thing so what I would do is use a video editor and export them as .mp4 that should fix the issue